# How to run a script when accessing a specific non existing path?

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, scripts

I have some path I have to access, which is the result of mounting.

I would like the mounting to be automatic, via a script, and I want that script to run just before an error is thrown from not being able to access the path.

For example, assume the script is

```
echo scripting!
mkdir -p /non_existing_path
```

and I want it to run when trying to access (in any way) to the path `/non_existing_path`.

So when I do for example

```
cd /non_existing_path
```

or

```
touch /non_existing_path/my_file.txt
```

It would always succeed, with the output `scripting!`. In reality, the script would be more elaborated than that.

---

Is this possible at all?

Comment: You want the script to run on drive mount ?

Comment: related: [How Do I use autofs to map a USB drive by its ID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42260/how-do-i-use-autofs-to-map-a-usb-drive-by-its-id/276873)

Comment: @Liso no, I want the script to run just before getting the error `-bash: cd: /non_existing_path: No such file or directory.` It can be any script, and is not related to mounting

Comment: And why is that? You can prevent that with `mkdir -p` just like in your snippets. If you **really** want to make sure directory is exist, can't you just create small snippets to see *if dir not exist, then create it and run following, otherwise run following*. If that's the case, its easy to do with bash script.

Comment: @Liso as I said, the script is more elaborated. I want to mount a different directory depending on conditions, I want to log differently depending on conditions, I want to fail differently. i want the operating system to call a specific script upon accessing a specific path. Is it possible?